# What changes on UILabel in iOS 8?

Tags: uilabel, ios8

I have try to use the XCode GM with iOS 8 simluator, but when using UILabel some unexcepted effect happened, just as the text's height wrong or the label's frame wrong, why this happened, because I add the Label in drawRect?

Where can I get the infos about the changes?